# How useful is a recursive formula with too many parameters?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion

For a combinatorial enumeration problem that requires finding $f(n)$, I managed to come up with a recursive formula that involves around $n$ parameters. For example, while the Fibonacci recursion $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$ involves only $1$ parameter, the formula I obtained looks like $F(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)$ equaling to an expression of $F$'s with smaller inputs. I tried my best to come up with a recursion that involves a constant number of parameters but could not do so.

Before this problem, I have never encountered recurrence relations where the number of parameters depends on the size of the input, namely $n$. So, **how "acceptable" are these recursions as solutions to enumeration problems, as inelegant as they seem?** I ask this because I have not seen them in any combinatorics literature I have read and don't know how people deal with them.

Sorry for not being able to provide a specific example. The problem I am working on is for research that I cannot disclose.

Comment: $$\mathbb N^n \text{ is isomorphic to } \mathbb N$$ so really you are only ever dealing with arity 1 functions.  Good luck with your secret research.

Comment: One example of a recurrence relation which looks like this is for the Catalan numbers where $C_0=1$ and $C_{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^n C_iC_{n-i}$. We are still able to come up with a nice closed form for $C_n$ by using generating functions